# The text of the message will be out of the parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Development Environment
・ react
・ typescript
・ styled-components

The messages are displayed using the map.
If the text is long, the text will protrude from the parent.

I want the text to wrap around the parent if it extends beyond it.
Even if you apply box-sizing to the parent tag, if the text in {message.data.body} is too long, it will stick out from the parent.

```
const Main = styled.main`
  padding-left: 54px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(160px, 400px) 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const Message = styled.li<TMessage>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: ${({ user }: TMessage) => (user ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start')};
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  .right {
    margin-right: 8px;
    background: #0068b4;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    white-space: pre;
  }
  .left {
    background: #f0f2f5;
    color: ${({ user }: TMessage) => (user ? '#FFFFFF' : '#000000')};
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
    word-break: break-word;
    max-width: 870px;
  }
`;

return (
  <MatchContainer>
    <section className="section-one">
      <div></div>
    </section>
    <section className="section-two">
      <div></div>
      <div className="meessage-container">
        <section className="bubble-message">
            <div>
              <ul>
   　　　　　　　　 {messages.map((message) =>
                <Message key={message.data.id} user={message.data.fromMe}>
                  {message.data.fromMe && (
                    <div className="flex gridgap-5 align-items-end">
                      <div className="right">{message.data.body}</div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                  {message.data.fromMe === false && (
                    <div className="flex gridgap-10 align-items-end">
                      <div className="left">{message.data.body}</div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Message>
              )}
              </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="room-profile"/>
      </div>
    </section>
  </MatchContainer>
);
```

> style.scss

```
  section {
      &.section-one{
        display: grid;
        /* grid-template-rows: 1fr auto; */
        align-content: start;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 16px;
        border-right: 2px solid #e1e6ed;
      }
      &.section-two{
        position: relative;
        border-right: 2px solid #e1e6ed;
        display: grid;
        overflow: auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
      }
      &.bubble-message {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
        border-right: 2px solid #e1e6ed;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
      &.room-profile {
        padding: 24px;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }

div {
  &.meessage-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(300px, 450px);
    overflow: auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add `overflow-wrap` or `word-wrap` css properties to the parent and set them to either `break-word` or `normal`

Comment: I applied overflow-wrap: normal to const Message, but it didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply both properties:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
```